# How to pass a parameter from MainActivity to App.cs in method Resume

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have no idea how to pass a parameter from **MainActivity.cs**

this code from **App.cs**

```
 protected override void OnResume(int notificationId)
        {
            
            MainPage = new AppShell(notificationId);
            
        }
```

I plan to pass a number in the "notificationId" parameter. To find a row in the database by "notificationId".

Comment: `OnResume` doesn't accept any parameters.  And you typically don't want to completely replace the existing navigation when the app resumes - the user expects to return to the same place in the app where they previously were.  Are you trying to deal with the user tapping on a push notification while the app is backgrounded?

Comment: yes. I thought that after taking a parameter in the Resume method, I could use "if" end "else if" to solve with notifications.

Comment: Have you read the docs on using notifications?  They contains samples that demonstrate how to respond to nofitications

Answer (score 0):

If you're integrating push notification(e,g `Azure notification hubs`) into your application , `OnResume` is not the appropriate method to handle this .

Actually every push notification kit has its own trigger method when receiving notification (or tapping on the notification alert) .

For example , we can handle the notification in method `OnPushNotificationReceived` with Azure notification .

```
// Set the delegate for receiving messages
NotificationHub.SetListener(new SampleNotificationListener());

// The notification listener implementation
public class SampleNotificationListener : Java.Lang.Object, INotificationListener
{
    public void OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Message received with title {message.Title} and body {message.Body}");
    }
}
```

Refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin#getting-started-with-xamarinandroid.

Then we can use [Messaging Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send the data to Forms project if you want .

Something like

```
//Android
public void OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<object,int >(this, "Hi",notificationId);
    }
```

```
//Forms App.cs

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object,int> (this, "Hi", (sender,id) =>
{
    MainPage = new AppShell(id);
});
```

Comment: May I ask have you solved the problem? If you have any other question please let me know.